Plant ID - and how to propagate it
This picture was taken in the old neighborhood of Jaffa, now part of Tel-Aviv. I have no idea if this tree is native. This area of town, with old buildings has many trees which have been planted in the 1940's and earlier and stand to this day. Few are unique and are difficult to find in nurseries. I am now attempting to take cuttings from several trees for propagation. Most are Ficus trees. I thought it was a Ficus until I saw the inflorescence and realized it was something completely different. Attempts at taking detailed photos of the flowers were unsuccessful, so I cannot see how many petals each flower has.
Any idea what that tree is? Does it propagate by cuttings?

I think it might be a Phytolacca dioica. If that's the case, it's not a tree but rather a giant herb.

it's a tree ...
